# extract the first n characters from concatenated strings

Tags: r, string, extract

I've a data frame with two columns: `id` and `value`.

```
id <- seq(1,5)
value <- c("123;21232;78678",
           "4575;23423",
           "1245;45757;45375;39873",
           "787;536453;1121;3232;58684;2434",
           "444;44444;4444;444")

df <- data.frame(id, value)
df$value <- as.character(df$value)
```

I need to extract the first two digits of each number (separated by `;`). The output would look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_extract_all` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    mutate(value_2 = map_chr(str_extract_all(value, "\\b(\\d{2})"), 
       str_c, collapse=";"))
# id                           value           value_2
#1  1                 123;21232;78678          12;21;78
#2  2                      4575;23423             45;23
#3  3          1245;45757;45375;39873       12;45;45;39
#4  4 787;536453;1121;3232;58684;2434 78;53;11;32;58;24
#5  5              444;44444;4444;444       44;44;44;44
```

Or with `str_replace_all`

```
df %>%
    mutate(value_2 = str_replace_all(value, "(^|;)(..)[^;]+", "\\2;") %>%
       trimws(whitespace = ";"))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df$value_2 <- sapply(regmatches(df$value, 
       gregexpr("\\b(\\d{2})", df$value)), paste, collapse=";")
```

---

Or with `gsub` from `base R`

```
trimws(gsub("(^|;)(..)[^;]+", "\\2;", df$value, perl = TRUE), whitespace = ";")
#[1] "12;21;78"          "45;23"             "12;45;45;39"  
#[4] "78;53;11;32;58;24" "44;44;44;44"
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! I am interested in the dplyr solution. However, I've noticed that when I view df data with results, the new column value_2 appears as follows: c("12", "21", "78"). Is there any way to make it the same format as column value? thanks!

Comment: @user9292 issue was the `str_extract_all` returns a `list` of `vectors` instead of a single character string.  With `map`, it is looping over the list and `paste/str_c` together

Answer (score 2):

Using just base R:

```
df$value_2 = sapply(strsplit(df$value, ';'), function(i){
    paste(substr(i, 1, 2), collapse = ';')
})
```

This goes row by row and separates each string by the semicolons, then pulls out the first two characters and returns them into a new string separated by semicolons.

This will give you:

```
  id                           value           value_2
1  1                 123;21232;78678          12;21;78
2  2                      4575;23423             45;23
3  3          1245;45757;45375;39873       12;45;45;39
4  4 787;536453;1121;3232;58684;2434 78;53;11;32;58;24
5  5              444;44444;4444;444       44;44;44;44
```